# Google API - Refresh Token

Tags: php, google-api

Estou tentando obter um novo `access_token` depois dele ter expirado.
Eu já guardo no banco as informações que recebo como retorno no primeiro acesso do cliente:

> {"access_token":"TOKEN","refresh_token":"TOKEN","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"created":1320790426}

Depois que esse token expira eu preciso solicitar um novo, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$token['access_token']  = $db->dados[0]['access_token'];
$token['refresh_token'] = $db->dados[0]['refresh_token'];
$token['token_type']    = $db->dados[0]['token_type'];
$token['expires_in']    = $db->dados[0]['expires_in'];
$token['created']       = $db->dados[0]['created'];

$client->setAccessToken(json_encode($token));

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    echo "Expirado !";
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
} else {
    echo "Valendo !";
}
```

O problema é que sempre recebo essa mensagem de erro:

> Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }

Comment: Pelo que sei as Apis do Google Search foram arquivadas, por isso não sei se ainda funcionam.

Comment: No caso estou tentando acessar a API do Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

Comment: E se você testar por esse link do Google funciona, https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
Ma o meu está dando erro...